# F# - ¿Porque no puedo declarar un nombre dentro del bloque `try with`?

Tags: .net, f#

El código funciona al si llamar una funcion o asignar un valor dentro del bloque `try-catch`:

```
module public test 

open System

let testing = 

  let divide = fun a b -> a / b

  try
    divide 100 0
  with
    | :? System.DivideByZeroException as ex -> printfn "Exception! %s (ex.Message); None.Value
```

o

```
module public test 

open System

let testing = 

  let divide = fun a b -> a / b

  let mutable num = divide 100 10

  try
    num = divide 100 0
  with
    | :? System.DivideByZeroException as ex -> printfn "Exception! %s (ex.Message); None.Value
```

Al declarar un nombre dentro del bloque no me deja:

```
module public test 

open System

let testing = 
/*
El bloque que sigue a este objeto 'let' está sin finalizar. Cada bloque de 
código es una expresión y debe tener un resultado. 'let' no puede ser el 
elemento de código final en un bloque. Considere la posibilidad de asignar a 
este bloque un resultado explícito.
*/
  let divide = fun a b -> a / b

  try
    let num = 100
    let num2 = 20
    divide num num2
  with
    | :? System.DivideByZeroException as ex -> printfn "Exception! %s (ex.Message); None.Value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto se debe a que dentro de los bloques `try-catch` no es posible declarar variables. Esto es así para evitar que no lleguen a declarar nuevas variables por haberse lanzado algún error en alguna parte del bloque `try`, lo que llevaría a la ejecución del bloque `catch` sin declarar las otras variables. Por lo tanto, debes declarar las variables fuera de los bloques `try-catch` y podrás asignarles valores dentro del bloque `try-catch`.

> Por lo tanto son posibles los dos primeros códigos que incluyes en tu pregunta.
>
> Para que el tercero sea válido debes declarar las variables fuera del bloque `try` de la siguiente manera:
>
> ```
> module public test 
>
> open System
>
> let testing = 
> /*
> El bloque que sigue a este objeto 'let' está sin finalizar. Cada bloque de 
> código es una expresión y debe tener un resultado. 'let' no puede ser el 
> elemento de código final en un bloque. Considere la posibilidad de asignar a 
> este bloque un resultado explícito.
> */
>
>     let divide = fun a b -> a / b
>     let num = 0
>     let num2 = 0
>
>     try
>         num = 100
>       num2 = 20
>         divide num num2
>     with
>         | :? System.DivideByZeroException as ex -> printfn "Exception! %s (ex.Message); None.Value
> ```

De esta manera debería solucionarse tu problema.

Comment: muchas gracias, claro f# no permite declarar nombres sin valor!

Comment: No debería ser "let mutable num = 0"?

Comment: si olvide el mutable pero a que me referia es que no puedes usar let dentro try cacth